# accept button on Terraria not working

Tags: terraria

I have my friend's IP address and port, but when I click the accept button on the port screen my computer just lags a bit and acts like I never clicked the button!

Comment: That means the connection isn't working.

Comment: Can others connect to his server? The problem could be on your friend's side.

Comment: Is your friend behind a router? When that's the case: 1. make sure you connect to the Internet IP of the router, not your firends LAN IP. 2. the router needs to be configured to forward port 7777 to your friends LAN IP (check the manual, when it doesn't help ask on superuser.com).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the port is 7777 and that you're using your friend's exact IP address.  (cmd - ipconfig).  Terraria takes little space and should not lag unless something is terribly wrong.  If this does not work try reinstalling the game or verifying the game cache to ensure no files are corrupted.

Comment: Verifying the game cache is actually enough ;).